# background image appears only when refreshed on safari on ipad

Tags: html, css

my background image for the body appears cut off initially and appears correctly when refreshed.

```css
body {
  background-position: center;
  background-image:url(../interface_images/assessment/genericbackgroundx.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

I converted the image to .gif, but that doesn't fix it. 
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the bg image from the body to the first div inside. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

change the background-attachment value to fixed.

- With "scroll" (default) - The background image will scroll with the
  page.
- With "fixed" - The background image will not scroll with the
  page.
- With "local" - The background image will scroll with the
  element's contents

You can read a lot more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment)